# Twig upload data from entity in different bundle

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, twig

I want to get data where the entity is in a different bundle:

Twig in MainBundle:

```
     {% extends 'MainBundle:eshop:main.html.twig' %}

     {% set products = getClassVars(Product) %}

    {% block body %}


    <div class="container main-container">

    <!-- Main component call to action -->


    <div id="productslider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

        <?php $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();?>
        <?php    $products= $em
        ->getRepository('ProductBundle:Product')->findAll(); ?>
        {%
        for product in  products %}
            {% if date(product.createdDate )> date('-1days') %}


                <div class="item">
                    <div class="product">
                        <a class="add-fav tooltipHere" data-toggle="tooltip"
                           data-original-title="Add to Wishlist"
                           data-placement="left">

                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
                        </a>

                        <div class="image">
                            <div class="quickview">
                                <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs btn-quickview" href="ajax/product.html"
                                   data-target="#productSetailsModalAjax">Quick View </a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="{{ asset('app_dev.php/product/')~product.id~"/show" }}"><img
                                        class="img-responsive" alt="img"
                                        src="{{ asset('bundles/imageproducts/')~ product.imageName }}"
                                        height="250" width="200"></a>

                            <div class="promotion"><span class="discount">15% OFF</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="description">
                            <h4>
                                <a href="{{ asset('app_dev.php/product/')~product.id~"/show" }}">{{ product.libelle }} </a>
                            </h4>

                            <div class="grid-description">
                                <p>{{ product.libelle }}  </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-description">
                                <p> {{ product.description }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="size">XL / XXL / S </span></div>
                        <div class="price"><span>$25</span></div>
                        <div class="action-control"><a class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="add2cart"><i
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"> </i> Add to cart </span>
                            </a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Product entity:

```
<?php

 namespace ProductBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToMany;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
 use ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository;

/**
 * Produit
 *     @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
  * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\Table(name="produit")
  */
  class Product
  {
   /**
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
   private $id;
```

> Unknown "getClassVars" function.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select('Product')->from('ABCBundle:Product', 'Product')
   ->leftJoin('XYZBundle:Category', 'Category', 'Category.productID = Product.id')
   ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

of just make join

Product.yml

```
oneToOne:
    description:
        targetEntity: Description
        mappedBy: product
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
```

Description.yml

```
oneToOne:
    product:
        targetEntity: Product
        mappedBy: description
        joinColumn:
            name: product_id
            referencedColumn: id
```

also 
if you already created a relation for entities that it should return easily.

Comment: i changed in my controller in User controller to load Products where Product in different bundle i didn't need to add any annotation thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

like i said it's 100% lack of concentration
i post the answer if anyone need it so we have :

MainBundle wish have User

ProductBundle wish have Product

```
 <?php

 namespace MainBundle\Controller;

 use ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository;
 use ProductBundle\Entity\Product;

 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * User controller.
 *
 */
 class UserController extends Controller
 {

public function indexAction()
{

    $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $products= $em->getRepository('ProductBundle:Product')->findAll();



    return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', array(
        'products' => $products,


    ));

  }}
```